# Meteor: getting info from a single document upon click

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a test meteor app that can be found here:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/ckgN6GL4msQn4Ms5h/Jobs

I have a nav bar, where each item is a document in the Jobs collection.

What I'm wanting to do, is when a user clicks on one of the jobs, the main summary page will show that specific jobs info (name, creation time, user etc.)

I'm trying to achieve this by setting a session variable to the id of that job (this appears to work). Then query from the database and pull the document where the id matches what is stored in the session variable. From that, display the name, creation, username in the summary div

The problem is that nothing appears in the summary div after I click a link

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code? Or, is there a better way to achieve this type of setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your helper "summary" as I see, so it's never called. Try using "with" in your template.

```
<template name="summary">
  {{#with summary}}
    <div id="summaryContainer">
      <p>Name: {{name}}</p>
      <p>Created at: {{createdAt}}</p>
      <p>Username: {{username}}</p>
    </div>
  {{/with}}
</template>
```